# Is there anything else like WCF, for other platforms, OSes, languages?

Tags: .net, wcf

I find Windows Communication Foundation to be really great (and only getting better in 4.5 with integrated compression among others) for all kinds of communication needs and I truly enjoy programming in .NET.

Yet I really wonder how programmers in other languages deal with all their communication needs. Is there any other comparably comprehensive solution like WCF?

(I know Mono has parts of WCF, this question is about truly different approaches, platforms and OSes.)

Comment: **No.** WCF is pretty unique. Other OS and platforms often have certain parts of it - support for WS-* standards etc. - but there's to my knowledge no WCF equivalent on other platforms offering that kind of breadth and depth of functionality and such a nice, unified programming model

Comment: That kind of explains why in so many years I have never heard of an alternative to WCF either.

Comment: I would not say that it is "unique". For example Apache CXF provides very complex features set for Java programmers - it probably doesn't provides some features like duplex communication (which is the worst part of WCF) but in case of SOAP and REST services it will provide much more than WCF.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka Funny, that worst part of WCF enabled me to write a very successful distributed reverse proxy, [PortFusion](http://portfusion.sourceforge.net), that works with all TCP protocols :)

Comment: @Cetin: By the worst part I mean duplex over HTTP. Net.tcp and named pipes are separate topic. You did very nice project and you make nice usage of WCF - well done! It doesn't mean that you wouldn't make the same just with directly using classes from `System.Net.Sockets` + async processing (completion ports). I'm 100% sure that in load tests and performance test the solution using sockets will perform much better because it would simply not execute overhead of generic API. Of course if you such scenarios aren't important for your main use case it's OK to use anything which makes the job done.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka Thanks for the tip. I am aware of the possibilities and I will take a look at other more direct options and even native languages once I start hitting limits or once there is user demand, especially in terms of memory usage on RAM-limited systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RemObjects SDK](http://www.remobjects.com/ro/) is a commercial component provided by [RemObjects Software](http://www.remobjects.com/) that provides WCF-like functionality between a whole range of platforms, protocols and languages.  While perhaps not as complete as WCF, RemObjects has been around a long time (since 2002) and it does provide a lot of features:

Platforms supported: .NET (since version 1.1 and including Mono), Delphi (version 7 and later, also including FreePascal on Linux), XCode (Objective-C and Cocoa), Silverlight, Javascript and Java (still in development I think)

Some things are easier than WCF, some things are harder, (and I only have experience of the .NET and Delphi platforms) but the approach is generally as follows:

- You use a GUI tool called the *Service Builder* (which is usually available as an IDE plugin) to define your services, parameters and structs and this generates an XML file called the *RODL* meta data file (similar to WSDL), from which interface and implementation files are generated for any or all of the supported platforms.  An async version of each call is also generated.
- You drop components onto a form to configure the channels and the message formats you wish to use and configure everything via these.  Many different channel components exist, e.g., HTTP, HTTPS, something called SuperHTTP which is bi-directional, TCP, SuperTCP, named pipes, UDP and broadcast channels, email, etc.  You can also choose between many different message formats SOAP, JSON, XML-RPC, a fast proprietary binary format, etc.
- Other WCF-like features include: *ZeroConf* which is similar to WCF server discovery; *Smart Services* allow you to easily publish the same service using multiple protocols simultaneously; it is extensible via events which can provide additional logging, security, etc. (similar to WCF IServiceBehaviors).

Comment: This is a wonderful answer I wish could upvote it multiple times. I especially like the existence of duplex communication support in SuperTCP.

Answer (score 0):

> Yet I really wonder how programmers in other languages deal with all their communication needs.

This is actually very interesting question because it comes to the biggest problems of .NET programmers. Developers on other platforms usually don't have "single API to rule them all" provided by "semi god" company. They usually have multiple choices and some of them are very specialized to solve single communication type in the most efficient way. So they first must understand the problem and after that select the most suitable API. .NET developers usually doesn't consider any other choice because they have WCF and WCF must solve everything, mustn't it?

Generally the more things single API can do the more complex it is. It requires more skills to use the API and more skills to add anything new to the API. I like WCF but it is the most complex and hard to use API (leave simple examples and try to use anything complex or integrate with other platform) in .NET world I have ever used and in the same time WCF (especially out-of-the box implementation) is not the API to solve every cross-process or cross-machine communication problem. Sometimes WCF is simply not suitable. As example I would use bidirectional communication where out-of-the box WCF implementation puts a lot of additional requirements and overhead. Another example is large data transfer - streaming transfer in SOAP service is not solution for passing tens (or more) MBs.

Comment: I have developed a distributed reverse proxy with WCF and tested it home using different computer connected in a gigabit LAN and direct download speed was exactly the same as download via my proxy which uses 2 terminal TcpClient instances and 1 duplex WCF service in between. 24 MB/s in **both**. I was hitting a HDD IO barrier with my little that day I guess but I hope redo it and do many new ones in the coming holiday ^_^ ...

Comment: Spare me the XML config files fantasy though. They are a royal pain in the ass and extremely clumsy and hard to maintain, *that* I obviously admit. Yet I am optimistic and believe it might help *some* others some*how* :)